# SwiftyJSON ArrayValue limited number of objects

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

I am facing weird problem while trying to get a `JSON` that has an array of `JSON` inside. Server API is fine since Android app and website are getting correct data, but on iOS I am getting only 50 objects or less in this array. If the array has less then 50 objects - I am getting correct data. Can it somehow be connected with `SwityJSON` limitations, or some other thing not allowing me to get whole JSON? Or is it 100% server issue?

Here is my code, but I am sure, it should be fine.

```
class func requestSelection(id: String, handler: @escaping (Selection?) -> Void) {
    let url = "selections/" + id

    APIModel.shared.requestWithLocation(.post, URL: url, parameters: nil) { data in

        guard let `data` = data else {
            handler(nil)
            return
        }

        let selection = data["selection"].to(type: Selection.self) as? Selection
        //I print "list" and its count is less or equals 50
        selection?.restaurants = data["selection"]["list"].to(type: Restaurant.self) as? [Restaurant]
        handler(selection)
    }
}

func requestWithLocation(_ httpmethod: Alamofire.HTTPMethod, URL: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandler) {

    let parametersWithLocation = self.addLocationTo(parameters: parameters)
    let url = self.serverAddress + "/" + URL

    self.alamofireRequest(url: url, method: httpmethod, parameters: parametersWithLocation) { data in
        completionHandler(data)
    }
}

private func addLocationTo(parameters: [String: AnyObject]?) -> [String: AnyObject] {
    var location: [String: Double] = [:]
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways) && locationManager.location != nil {
        location = [
            "lon": locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude,
            "lat": locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude,
        ]
    }
    var parametersWithLocation = parameters ?? [:]
    parametersWithLocation["location"] = location as AnyObject

    return parametersWithLocation
}

private func alamofireRequest(url: String, method: HTTPMethod, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandler) {
    Alamofire.request(url, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: User.shared.header).validate().responseJSON { response in
        guard let data = response.result.value else {
            print(response.result.error as NSError? as Any, url)
            completionHandler(nil)
            return
        }
        //debugPrint(JSON(data), url)
        completionHandler(JSON(data))
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see any code related to `SwiftyJSON`, but `SwiftyJSON` certainly does not cause the issue, maybe the `APIModel` class.

Comment: @vadian added more code

Comment: There's still no code related to `SwiftyJSON`.

Comment: @vadian really sorry, forgot one more function, `data` is `SwiftyJSON.JSON`, initiated in `alamofireRequest `

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with the swiftyjson, coz I have an api which returns somewhat 500 objects in a array, and swifty json handles it without a sweat.